# mysql query insert not working for one value but works for all the rest

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, insert

I am receiving vars from AS3 via php script and inserting into db. all the vars are being passed as you can see in the address bar .. ( which i would like to hide from public but dont know how) .. I then get the vars and insert to db table. all tables are set ok i think. I am catching the vars also for an echo. all vars working but "image_name" and its not translating to the $tmp_name for the echo either. Any ideas on this one ..
Here is the line in browser holding the vars.

```
http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/wordpress/?page_id=81imageName=WhitetailJackalope%2Epng&imageURL=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fxxx%2Fxxx%2FserverImages%2FwhiteTailJackalopeEgg%2Epng&imageID=40
```

here is the PHP

```
<?php


$tmp_id=$_GET['imageID'];
$tmp_url=$_GET['imageURL'];
$tmp_name=$_GET['imageName'];

mysql_connect("localhost", "xxx", "xxx") or die(mysql_error()); 
    mysql_query ( "INSERT INTO wp_image_data (`image_id`, `image_url`, `user_name`, `image_name`, `stage`)
        VALUES ('$tmp_id' , '$tmp_url' , '$current_user->user_login' , '$tmp_name' , 1)"); 
    echo 'Testing: ' . $tmp_id . '<br/>'; //displays ok
    echo 'Image: ' . $tmp_name . '<br/>'; //does not display or insert to table
    echo 'Owner: ' . $current_user->user_login . '<br/>'; //displays ok

?>
```

The table in the db for the image_name is VARCHAR(100) utf8_ganeral_ci

Any ideas ?

I have restructured the php as advised with the PDO format which seems to be good for me. Thank you for that information :)
Here is the restructured code. It works fine except for the image_name which i need to figure how to restructure my url now in wordpress.

```
try {

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$namedb", $userdb, $passdb);
$conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");      

$sql = "INSERT INTO wp_image_data (image_id, image_url, user_name, image_name, stage)
    VALUES ('$tmp_id', '$tmp_url', '{$current_user->user_login}', '$tmp_name', '1')"; 
$q = $conn->exec($sql);   
$conn = null; 
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}

    echo 'Testing: ' . $tmp_id . '<br/>';
    echo 'Image: ' . $tmp_name . '<br/>'; 
    echo 'Owner: ' . $current_user->user_login . '<br/>';
```

Now to work on the url ... YAY and while im doing that is there a way to hide the passed variables in the address bar ?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Where is the code that builds your URL with those querystring values?

Comment: in my flash. do you want me to post the flash code ?

Comment: @Flexxall do you want help with that portion also? Or have you fixed it?

Comment: @ethorn10 Yes assistance with the url passing and restructure would be great.

Comment: @Flexxall you should probably post that as a new question - asking for help with creating the url from flash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL needs reconstructed to include an ampersand after the page_id value:

`http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/wordpress/?page_id=81&imageName=WhitetailJackalope%2Epng&imageURL=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fxxx%2Fxxx%2FserverImages%2FwhiteTailJackalopeEgg%2Epng&imageID=40`

Answer (score 0):

You should set up your query and echo it to see what is being passed.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO wp_image_data (`image_id`, `image_url`, `user_name`, `image_name`, `stage`)
        VALUES ('$tmp_id' , '$tmp_url' , '$current_user->user_login' , '$tmp_name' , 1)";

echo $query;
```

I would recommend using curly brackets around `$current_user->user_login`:

```
{$current_user->user_login}
```

You need to immediately stop using `mysql_` functions. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. See my comment for details.